# Pass array has object property from foxpro (to c#)

Tags: com, foxpro

I'm trying to have a class that hold a array and use that class in some COM calls (I makes using C#).

So, I've got my classes like this:

```
DEFINE CLASS Logistics_Columns AS Session OLEPUBLIC
 DIMENSION COLUMNS_ARRAY[1]

 DIMENSION COLUMNS_ARRAY_COMATTRIB(4)
 COLUMNS_ARRAY_COMATTRIB(1) = 0 
 COLUMNS_ARRAY_COMATTRIB(2) = "COLUMNS_ARRAY"
 COLUMNS_ARRAY_COMATTRIB(3) = "COLUMNS_ARRAY"
 COLUMNS_ARRAY_COMATTRIB(4) = "Array"
ENDDEFINE 

DEFINE CLASS Logistics_Column AS Session OLEPUBLIC
 COLUMN_NAME = .NULL.
 DIMENSION COLUMN_NAME_COMATTRIB(4)
 COLUMN_NAME_COMATTRIB(1) = 0 
 COLUMN_NAME_COMATTRIB(2) = "COLUMN_NAME"
 COLUMN_NAME_COMATTRIB(3) = "COLUMN_NAME"
 COLUMN_NAME_COMATTRIB(4) = "Character"

 COLUMN_TYPE = .NULL.
 DIMENSION COLUMN_TYPE_COMATTRIB(4)
 COLUMN_TYPE_COMATTRIB(1) = 0 
 COLUMN_TYPE_COMATTRIB(2) = "COLUMN_TYPE"
 COLUMN_TYPE_COMATTRIB(3) = "COLUMN_TYPE"
 COLUMN_TYPE_COMATTRIB(4) = "Character"

 COLUMN_WIDTH = .NULL.
 DIMENSION COLUMN_WIDTH_COMATTRIB(4)
 COLUMN_WIDTH_COMATTRIB(1) = 0 
 COLUMN_WIDTH_COMATTRIB(2) = "COLUMN_WIDTH"
 COLUMN_WIDTH_COMATTRIB(3) = "COLUMN_WIDTH"
 COLUMN_WIDTH_COMATTRIB(4) = "Integer" 

 COLUMN_PRECISION = .NULL.
 DIMENSION COLUMN_PRECISION_COMATTRIB(4)
 COLUMN_PRECISION_COMATTRIB(1) = 0 
 COLUMN_PRECISION_COMATTRIB(2) = "COLUMN_PRECISION"
 COLUMN_PRECISION_COMATTRIB(3) = "COLUMN_PRECISION"
 COLUMN_PRECISION_COMATTRIB(4) = "Integer" 
ENDDEFINE
```

In C# for the Logistics_Column**s** class, COLUMNS_ARRAY is not seen as an array.

Yet or the Logistics_Column class all 4 properties are correctly seen as string or integer.

I guess "Array" (`COLUMNS_ARRAY_COMATTRIB(4) = "Array"`)isn't the right literal value to indicate an array.

But then, what is?

Comment: I don't think you can do it. Maybe consider using a collection instead of an array?

Comment: You're right. I'll use a Collection wrapper which is accessible through COM so C# will be able to use it directly.

Answer (score 0):

As planned I created a custom collection wrapper.

It's basically a foxpro class of type `Session OLEPUBLIC` which store a `Collection` and wraps its methods.

Regarding the performance I think it adds some noticeable overhead, but it's the best method I could eventually come with.